# Bound object never be null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

For instance, there is some object that will be model for strongly-typed view:

```
class SomeModel {
    public string SomeUsualField { get; set; }
}
```

Further, some action exists in controller that will work with object specified above:

```
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel obj)
{ 
    return View(obj);
}
```

So the question is why `obj` isn't a `null` while `Index` action first called? It's created new instance of `SomeModel` class with null `SomeUsualField`.

Comment: Is SomeModel a struct? If so, it will automatically initialize obj to a new SomeModel, and assign all default values.

Comment: @xixonia Definetely no. It's a class as you can see above in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC model binding infrastructure tries to fill all properties with data coming from the request object (query string, form fields, ...). Therefore it creates an instance of all parameters of the controller to try to match the properties.
Because you don't pass a SomeUsualField, it is null, but the parameter object has an empty instance.

You can initialize the property SomeUsualField when you call http://localhost/MySite/MyController/Index?SomeUsualField=test. The property SomeUsualField will automagically initialized with 'test'

If you don't want the parameter to be set, you can leave it away and make a 2nd action with the attribute [HttpPost]. A good tutorial is the [music store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5).

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{  
    var obj = new SomeModel();
    return View(obj); 
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel obj) 
{  
    // update logic
    return View(obj); 
}
```

Comment: Ok. How can I determine what `obj` is absolutely new (in case of first time calling the `Index` action)? What is your approach for that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. As I said, obj will be created by the model binder through reflection and is a new object. If the modelbinder would find a matching property, the object would be initiialized. You can try that when you call http://localhost/MySite/MyController/Index?SomeUsualField=test. Then the obj would be initialized.

Comment: Sorry for my ugly English. I mean is there any way to get `obj` = null in Index method when it called first time (e.g. when page is open first time)?

Comment: I think, you would have to write your own model binder, but that's hard work and I don't think it would be reasonable. Why does it have to be null?

Comment: I asked you about it in my first comment :) Hmm... As you can see, I use `return View(obj);` in code. And I have some validation attributes , say `[Required]` on alone `SomeUsualField`. View consists of a form that have one `<input type="text" />` and `@Html.ValidationSummary()` somewhere in a `View`. So then user first time comes to the page, he faced with triggered validation. How can I avoid this and get validation fired only then user submitted form?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Why do you have the parameter at all? I will add a sample

Comment: I know about 2nd-post-only-method-technique, but how can I make it in only one method? There is a not some complicated logic and it would be very comfortable for me to have only one method to make sure code is clear. Another one way is to check is forn was submitted by user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5334/discussion-between-slfan-and-kseen)

Comment: check if your obj is null before returning view.

Comment: @Sharique: his problem is that obj is NEVER null, because it is initialized by the model binder